# deep roll of blue at the tops

Tags: meaning, terminology, ambiguity

I want some help with [my question](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2564321) about the meaning of  “deep roll of blue at the tops”:

> "The men were dressed in blue, of the same shade as their hats, and wore well-polished boots with a deep roll of blue at the tops." (The Wonderful Wizard of Oz - Chapter 2 - Describing the Munchkins)

Which part is the "top"? Is the roll like a curl over the toes? Or it could be also a cuff at the top of the shank, where the top of a boot will hit on the leg?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find a blue one, but here's a roll top boot...
[image]